PowerShell code to check the certificates expiring in 90 days on a multiple azure servers
By using the below code, I can get the number of certificates which are expiring in the current server. How can I modify this code to get the name of the certificates which are expiring in 90 days on a multiple remote servers?
# Define an array to store certificate paths
$certPaths = @(
    "Cert:\LocalMachine\My"
 
  
)
# Initialize a counter for certificates expiring soon
$certificatesExpiringSoonCount = 0
# Calculate the date 90 days from now
$expiryThreshold = (Get-Date).AddDays(90)
# Loop through each certificate path
foreach ($certPath in $certPaths) {
    # Get all certificates in the current store
    $certificates = Get-ChildItem -Path $certPath
    #$certificates
    foreach ($cert in $certificates) {
        # Check if the certificate expiry date is in the future and within the next 90 days
        if ($cert.NotAfter -gt (Get-Date) -and $cert.NotAfter -lt $expiryThreshold) {
            # Increment the counter for certificates expiring soon
            $certificatesExpiringSoonCount++
        }
    }
}
# Output the total number of certificates expiring soon
Write-Output "Total number of certificates expiring in 90 days: $certificatesExpiringSoonCount"


Where are you executing the PowerShell script? On VM or other place? Can you confirm if the remote machines are Azure VMS?

I have a graph script that does this for enterprise and registered apps, but not Azure VM servers locally imported certs specifically. If you can remote powershell to the remote servers, your working logic should be able to be run against multiple remote machines using invoke-command -computername $arrayOfMachines -scriptblock {<your code>}. You can optionally add -credential (get-credential) after the last }  if necessary.

@KevinLu-MSFT remote machines are azure VM, I'm running the script from my client VDI not on those remote servers

@Sushmithashetty Since the remote servers are Azure VMs, I suggest that you can use the az vm run-command invoke to run the powershell script on multiple servers. Please refer to my answer and check if it can work.

Based on your requirement, you need to run the PowerShell script on multiple Azure VM from Clent VDI.
To meet your requirement, I suggest that you can use the Azure CLI: az vm run-command invoke to run the PowerShell script.
For example:
az vm run-command invoke  --command-id RunPowerShellScript --name win-vm -g my-resource-group --scripts @script.ps1 

Before you running the Azure CLI, you need to run the az login command to authenticate. You need to make sure that the account you used to run Azure CLI have the access to all Azure VMs.
For more detailed info, you can refer to this doc: Run scripts in your Windows VM by using action Run Commands
